# python silero tts импорт после попытки запуска другого .py

Tags: python, tts

у меня есть tts часть кода, которую использую в main части tts.py:

```
import os
import shutil
import torch
from playsound import playsound
import colorful as cf`

cache_dir = "tts_cache"
def generate_audio(model, text, speaker, sample_rate,):
    audio_paths = model.save_wav(text=text, speaker=speaker, sample_rate=sample_rate,put_accent=1,put_yo=1)
    file_name = f"{text}.wav"
    os.rename(audio_paths, file_name)
    shutil.copy(file_name, cache_dir)
    os.remove(file_name)
    cached_path = os.path.join(cache_dir, file_name)
    return cached_path`

def get_cached_audio(text):
    cached_path = os.path.join(cache_dir, f"{text}.wav")
    if os.path.exists(cached_path):
        return cached_path
    return None

def generate_or_get_cached_audio(model, text, speaker, sample_rate):
    cached_audio = get_cached_audio(text)
    if cached_audio:
        print(cf.orange("Нашли кэш"))
        return cached_audio
    else:
        print(1)


def play_voice(text:str):
    device = torch.device('cpu')
    torch.set_num_threads(6)
    local_file = 'models/v3_1_ru.pt'
    model = torch.package.PackageImporter(local_file).load_pickle("tts_models", "model")
    model.to(device)
    sample_rate = 24000
    speaker='baya'
    audio = generate_or_get_cached_audio(model, text, speaker, sample_rate)
    playsound(f"tts_cache/{text}.wav")
```

Но для того чтобы она заимпортилась, нужна попытка запуска, другого py вот так: `/bin/python3 "/home/fd/Рабочий стол/voice_assistant/main.py" /bin/python3 "/home/fd/Рабочий стол/voice_assistant/test.py"`

При этом остальное, все нормально, работает

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Что значит «заимпортилась», что такое «попытка запуска», что мешает «заимпортить» без «попытки запуска» и какое отношение ко всему этому имеет приведённая команда /bin/python3 и файл main.py?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял твою проблему, тебе нужно импортировать функции из файла `tts.py` в другой файл `main.py`.
Вот как сделать это:

1. В файле `tts.py` ты должен добавить следующий код внизу:

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    play_voice("текст для преобразования в речь")
```

Это позволит запустить функцию `play_voice` только в случае, если файл `tts.py` запускается напрямую, а не импортируется.

2. В файле `main.py` ты можешь импортировать функции из `tts.py` следующим образом:

```py
from tts import play_voice

# Далее вы можете вызвать импортированную функцию по вашему усмотрению
play_voice("текст для преобразования в речь")
```

Теперь, когда ты запускаешь файл `main.py`, функция `play_voice` из файла `tts.py` будет импортирована и вызвана в `main.py`.